# How to adjust the printing scale of a a UML diagram in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a 54 page UML diagram to print.  I want to shrink the image size or pages size so there is no more than 12 pages to print?  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm not quite seeing the question here - short of "shrink the font and reduce the margins" or "delete some parts" what do you see the answer being?

Comment: @Flexo: do you know the EA product? The answer will have to do with how you set up the Print dialog.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Open the diagram
2. Use Diagram->Properties
3. On the Diagram tab, click "Advanced..." under Page Setup
4. Click the "Custom" radio button and choose the number of pages wide and tall

Answer (score 0):

you can also CTRL+A mark all and then paste it complete in e.g. Word.

That works and you can use all resize/etc. Options from word.

Comment: for a 54 page diagram, it will crash Word. Large diagrams will take a lot of memory in the clipboard and applications tend to not like that